# ls formatting inside watch command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls, watch

When I do `ls /dev/tty*`, I see the following output:

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty12  /dev/tty17  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty44  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty58  /dev/tty62  /dev/ttyS0
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty13  /dev/tty18  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty54  /dev/tty59  /dev/tty63  /dev/ttyS1
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty14  /dev/tty19  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty6   /dev/tty7   /dev/ttyS2
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty15  /dev/tty2   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty56  /dev/tty60  /dev/tty8   /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty16  /dev/tty20  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty34  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty57  /dev/tty61  /dev/tty9
```

The formatting is well and I can see all the files in modest block inside terminal.
But when I run this command such a way `watch -d -n1 'ls /dev/tty*'`, I see:

```
Every 1.0s: ls /dev/tty*                                                                                                                                                        debian: Wed Jun 30 21:08:06 2021

/dev/tty
/dev/tty0
/dev/tty1
/dev/tty10
/dev/tty11
/dev/tty12
/dev/tty13
/dev/tty14
/dev/tty15
/dev/tty16
/dev/tty17
/dev/tty18
/dev/tty19
/dev/tty2
/dev/tty20
/dev/tty21
...
```

So the output listed in vertical and doesn't fit my screen. What is the reason? How can I solve this?

Comment: So you want the output in watch to be the same as in regular ls?

Comment: @JeffSchaller deleted his answer after thinking it would be wrong, but I think it was the right solution, adding option ´-x´ to ´ls´.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the reason?

When `watch` executes commands they are not connected to the
terminal. In other words, `isatty(3)` returns 0. You can use the
following isatty.c to check if a command is connected to the terminal
when it's ran:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", isatty(STDOUT_FILENO));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc isatty.c -o isatty
```

Run in your terminal emulator:

```
$ ./isatty
1
```

Run it in watch:

```
$ watch ./isatty
Every 2.0s: ./isatty                                                                                                                                                              darkstar: Wed Jun 30 20:42:51 2021

0
```

> How can I solve this?

Use `-C` option with ls in watch:

```
watch -d -n1 'ls -C /dev/tty*'
```

Comment: You don't need a new program, just something like `test -t 1 && echo tty || echo not`

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above is fine, since `ls` offers an option to perform the same kind of work it does when it detects a TTY. But in case you ever want to do this on some other command - that doesn't have such an option - an easy way is this:

```
$ watch 'unbuffer ls /dev/tty*'
```

`unbuffer` [1] basically creates a tty, and uses it to stop the buffering done otherwise. A side effect, is that the programs it runs (in this case, `ls`) see a TTY - and therefore will do exactly what you would see in your terminal.

[1] https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer